# How to parse JSON "nearby search response" from Google Places API in Swift/Xcode

Tags: json, swift, xcode, google-maps, parsing

The Google Maps API is working great and I am getting the appropriate JSON response. However, I'm having trouble parsing the intricate and complex JSON response in order to obtain the specific information I need, such as location name. I have gone through basically every YouTube tutorial and online post I could find and nothing has helped me. I've included the current code I'm using and a link to the documentation outlining the JSON response I'm getting. Any help would be much appreciated!

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#nearby-search-and-text-search-responses

```
func nearbyLocations(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {


    let jsonUrlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=\(latitude),\(longitude)&radius=25&key=..."

    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, respone, err) in

        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] else { return }
            print(json)
        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("json error:", jsonErr)
        }

    }.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse normal like:

```
if let results = json["results"] as! [[String:Any]], let firstResult = results.first {
    let geometry = firstResult["geometry"] as! [String:Any]
    let location = geometry["location"] as! [String:Any]
    let lat = location["lat"] as! Double
    let lng = location["lng"] as! Double
}
```

Comment: No problem, Good luck! :D

Answer (score 0):

Use **`Codable`** to parse the *JSON response*.

**Models:**

```
struct Root: Codable {
    var results: [SearchResult]
    var status: String
}

struct SearchResult: Codable {
    var id: String
    var icon: String
    var name: String
    var placeId: String
    var reference: String
    var types: [String]
    var vicinity: String
    var geometry: Geometry
    var photos: [Photo]
    var openingHours: [String:Bool]?
}

struct Geometry: Codable  {
    var location: Location
}

struct Location: Codable  {
    var lat: Double
    var lng: Double
}

struct Photo: Codable {
    var height: Double
    var width: Double
    var photoReference: String
}
```

In the models above, add the `keys` as per your requirement. Also any of the above `keys` are not sure from the API, mark them as `optional`.

**Parsing:**

Parse the `data` your obtained in `URLSession.shared.dataTask` like,

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let root = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(root)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

**Usage:**

For the sample JSON response in the link you provided, you can access the properties of your response using `root` like,

```
root.status //OK

root.results.first?.name //Rhythmboat Cruises

root.results.first?.geometry.location.lat //-33.870775
```

Read more about `Codable` and how it works [here](https://hackernoon.com/everything-about-codable-in-swift-4-97d0e18a2999).

Comment: Do accept (tick on left) if the answer helped. Also, `Codable` is a much efficient and readable way with much lesser code that `JSONSerialization`.